# Count down values of key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, countdown

As said in the title, I need to add the values of my keys.
Here is what I'm doing :

```
 var repeat=ListeInterv[interv].week_data[numsemaine][intensit];
               for (var i=0;i<repeat;i++)
{tabpush.push(intensit);}
                console.log(tabpush);
```

For instance (Cardio is intensit):

```
    { Cardio : 3,
    }
```

I would have in my array :

```
[Cardio,Cardio,Cardio]
```

Then I'll use array.lengh, but I don't think this the best option...
I do this because I don't know how to count down the positive values :

```
{ sport1: 2,
  sport2 : -1,
  sport3 : 1,
}
```

Answer I would like (in both cases) is : 
      3

The Array method will be very long (I have a huge amount of data), my method is in an "if" for positive values. 
Any tips ?

Comment: Why is the second example `3`?

Comment: I just edited the question because I saw my mistake for looping in array, now I need to add the values of my keys... And the number of key is not fixed.